# XML - Не отображается активити

Tags: java, android, xml

Не отображается активити.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/rootLayout" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                tools:context="com.hideme.Menu">
    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="startGame"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_start"
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp" android:contentDescription="@string/desc"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Вместо активити пустой лист.

Comment: так у вас фон слоя белый и фон кнопки тоже белый

Comment: я на кнопку картинку повесил, поидее она же должна быть?

Comment: вместо `app:srcCompat` лучше использовать `android:src`, если ваша картинка не векторная. Что значит не отображается? фон белый есть или вообще пусто? Активити - контроллер, она вообще не отображается. Отображается разметка, прикрепленная к активити методом `setContentView()`/

Comment: Можете добавить код drawable?

Comment: Заменил app:scrCompat на android:src и убрал background отображается нормально, а если backround: white, то неотображается, но действие происходит onClick